# Forcing libraries that use requests library to use my proxy explicitly defined in get request

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, pycharm, rdflib

I'm trying to parse an RDF file using RDFLib. However, I have to use a proxy when making requests and I don't know how to get RDFLib to use my proxy.

```
import rdflib
g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse(url)
```

results in:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\d72704\PycharmProjects\Ontology\main.py", line 113, in
>
> Read_RDF()   File "C:\Users\d72704\PycharmProjects\Ontology\main.py", line 21, in
> Read_RDF
> g.parse(r'https://spec.edmcouncil.org/fibo/ontology/LOAN/LoansGeneral/Loans/Loan')
> File
> "C:\Users\d72704\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py",
> line 1234, in parse
> source = create_input_source(   File "C:\Users\d72704\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rdflib\parser.py",
> line 326, in create_input_source
> ) = _create_input_source_from_location(   File "C:\Users\d72704\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rdflib\parser.py",
> line 375, in _create_input_source_from_location
> input_source = URLInputSource(absolute_location, format)   File "C:\Users\d72704\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rdflib\parser.py",
> line 218, in **init**
> file = _urlopen(req)   File "C:\Users\d72704\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rdflib\parser.py",
> line 206, in _urlopen
> return urlopen(req)   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
> return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
> response = self._open(req, data)   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
> result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in
> _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1389, in https_open
> return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1349, in
> do_open
> raise URLError(err) urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
> remote host>

I can see that the requests library is being called by RDFLib
"C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py"
But I don't know how to pass my proxy values as I would do with a get request which does works

```
proxies = {myproxyhere}
r = requests.get(myurlhere, proxies=proxies, timeout=5)
```

I cannot alter my windows proxy settings due to admin constrains and if I try to set up the pycharm proxy it fails with this error

> Problem with connection: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the traceback more closely, you'll see that rdflib is not using the Requests library but rather the [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) module from the standard library.

Its documentation tells that it uses proxies defined by the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables if those are set.

So you can set them:

```
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://proxy.example:8899'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://proxy.example:8899'
```

(Requests also relies on those same environment variables, so the same solution will work with libraries that do use Requests.)